# Loop not working and not raising any error in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I am working with a list of df's, I would like to change this typo "-" for NA for every df row for every df column for every df in the list.

However when I run the next code and then unlist to verify if it worked, the output remains the same "-" insted of NA:

```
for(i in 1:length(df_list)){
      for(j in i){
        for(z in j){
          if(df_list[[i]][[j]][[z]] == "-"){
            return(NA)
          } else {
            df_list[[i]][[j]][[z]] 
          }
        }
      }
}

## unlist to verify ##
for(i in names(df_list)){
    assign(i, df_list[[i]], .GlobalEnv)
}

##verifying ##
df1[1, "col"]

// output //

"-"
```

Is there anyway to do this in R with other object?

Comment: In R for-loops always return NULL. That is so even when you use an explicit return(). On the other hand assignments inside for consequences will occur in the calling environment, which in the case of using a for loop from the console will be in the globalenv().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need for so many nested `for` loops, a simple `lapply` loop will change all `"-"` in all data frames to `NA`.

```
df_list <- lapply(df_list, function(x){
  is.na(x) <- x == "-"
  x
})
```

**Test data creation code**

```
f <- function(i){
  d <- data.frame(x = letters[1:5], y = 6:10, a = letters[1:5])
  d$x[sample(5, 1)] <- "-"
  d$a[sample(5, 2)] <- "-"
  d
}
df_list <- lapply(1:3, f)
rm(f)
```

Answer (score 3):

An option with `tidyverse` would be

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(purrr)
 map(df_list, ~ .x %>%
                  mutate(across(everything(), na_if, "-")))
```

Comment: He could also use  `mutate_all(na_if, "-") ` if he wants to check all columns

Comment: @IvnAnt `mutate_at` `mutate_all` are getting deprecated in favor of `across`.  WIthin `across` you can use the `select_helpers`  i.e. for all columns `everything()`.  Yes, they can also use `mutate_all`

Comment: And if you want to be safe (although `na_if` tends to do the right thing... `purrr::map(df_list, ~ .x %>% mutate(across(where(is.character), ~ na_if(., "-"))))
`

Comment: I'm just curious, is there any case where you would prefer `across`?

Comment: @IvnAnt  I like the `mutate_all`, `mutate_at` syntax as it is more compact.  But, `across` is more general i.e. suppose you want to find the number of rows per group.  With `mutate_all/at`, it returns multiple columns of `n()`.  WIth `mutate/across`, there is flexibility i.e. `iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% mutate(across(everything(), mean), n = n())`

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for your purpose?

```
lapply(df_list,function(v) replace(v,v=="-",NA))
```

---

Regarding the nest `for` loop in your code, you should not use `return(NA)`, since it doesn't assign new values to the existing data.frames, which is the reason that the output remains the same "-" insted of NA.

You can try the version like below

```
for(i in 1:length(df_list)){
      for(j in i){
        for(z in j){
          if(df_list[[i]][[j]][[z]] == "-"){
            df_list[[i]][[j]][[z]] <- NA
          }
        }
      }
}
```